# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) C Program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run this program with the command

./box2 5

```
/*
 * box2.c
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 19, 2014
 *      Author: Ian
 */
 #include <stdio.h>
 void printchars(char c, int n);
 int main( int argc, char*argv)
 {
    int n = argv[1];
    printchars('*', n);
    return 0;
 }

 void printchars(char c, int n)
 {
    int x;
    for (x = n + 2 ; x > 0; x--)
    {

        if (x != 1 && x != n)
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            int count = n;
            while (count - 2 != 0)
            {
                printf(" ");
                 count--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int num = n;
            while (num != 0)
            {
                printf("%c", c);
                num--;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
     }
 }
```

I always get the error Segmentation Fault(core dumped) each time i try it.

```
    *****
    *   *
    *   *
    *   *
    *   *
    *   *
    *****
```

This is what I should get.

I have no idea what to do to fix this. I get no errors when I compile and that error is the only thing that comes up when I try to run the program.

Comment: What have you tried? What output do you get? Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried inserting some print statements at various points to see if you reach them and where you crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 int main( int argc, char*argv)
```

since `argv` must be declared as a ptr-to-ptr-to-char. Likewise, this:

```
 int n = argv[1];
```

can't work. You need something like

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 ...
 int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: I changed both and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3015970 Did you supply a numeric argument when you started the program, as in `program 42`?

Comment: @user3015970 Then you forgot to recompile. It works here (although prints not quite the rectangle). For atoi() you should also `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess it was just not compiling. It worked now I will just need to fix the box. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3015970 This is still wrong. You aren't testing `argc` before trying to access `argv[1]`, which may not even exist if the user fails to provide an additional argument, and the program will then segfault.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` is a `char *`. You need to convert that to an `int`. You could do that by calling `atoi()` as follows:

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Note that this will not handle argument errors. Note also that your definition of `argv` is wrong: it should be `char * argv[]`.

Comment: A good practice is to first check argc as well to make sure it is 2 (remember the first one is the program name) or greater before trying to atoi it.

Comment: Absolutely. However I tend to try and stick as closely as possible to a question's main focus, rather than add, possibly very reasonable, digressions. Otherwise one should go into greater details about error prevention and handling.

Comment: Pointing out problems, in addition to or rather than downvoting, is more helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int main( int argc, char*argv)` to `int main( int argc, char**argv)`.